# Error during Karma Test execution

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, karma-jasmine

I have a problem current where my directives were build as following :

selectprice.directive.js file

(function() {
    'use strict';

```
angular
    .module('app.buyouts.selectPrice')
    .directive('selectPrice', selectPrice);
```

However when starting Karma, I get the following error:

Chrome 54.0.2840 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
  Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
  at app/buyouts/selectprice/selectprice.directive.js:5

I just don't know what to do. Maybe the directives aren't created properly? Can u please help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add angular to your **karma.config.js**
Example:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
    basePath: '../..',

    frameworks: [ 'mocha' , 'chai' ],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'assets/libs/angular.min.js',
      'assets/libs/angular-cookies.min.js',
      'assets/libs/angular-route.min.js',
      'assets/libs/angular-sanitize.min.js',            
      'assets/libs/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'test/unit/components/*.test.js'
    ]
```

Comment: I redefined the files as you said, including the angular libs, it worked however I get another error: 

encountered a declaration exception FAILED
        ReferenceError: module is not defined
            at Suite.<anonymous> (test/selectprice-directive-spec.js:5:14)
            at test/selectprice-directive-spec.js:1:1
Chrome 54.0.2840 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 2 of 2 (1 FAILED) (0.022 secs / 0.003 secs)

I'm doing the module injection in spec : 

beforeEach(module('app.buyouts.selectprice')); same declaration from the directive itself.

Do u have any ideas?

Comment: Did you add your src files in the files section?. Probably karma couldn't find the module. Your source files have to be included in files section also.

Comment: yes, I added every js file for the directive I'm trying to load.